# Keras ImageDataGenerator from directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to train a network from data that I have in a Dataframe. I have image paths and classes.
There are many image classes so splitting them into directories is not an option.
I only found beside the `flow_from_directory` function, the flow function which takes into an argument a `numpy` array and classes. However, the data will not even fit in RAM.
Is there any solution using Keras ?

## Edit 1:

Issue referenced in Github

- https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3295
- https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3338

Comment: How do you match image names with classes?

Comment: With a dictionary. Basically I want to use the `ImageDataGenerator`  in this use case, but unfortunately I cannot find any easy solution

Comment: Have you thought about putting every image in a separate format and then using your dictionary combined with `class_indices` in order to relabel your images?

Comment: It is easy to write another batch generator (see the last comment of the Github issue). But the image preprocessing module of Keras and especially the `ImageDataGenerator` doesn't provide an easy way to be integrated with a custom generator. I want just to benefit from its real time Image augmentation and the multitasking ability

Comment: But I meant obfuscation of `ImageDataGenerator` by another generator - which makes possible to use existing data augmentation modules.

Comment: Did you try reducing the batch_size parameter from `flow_from_directory`?